# X11 with window decorations on ubuntu mini distro

Tags: linux, x11

Goal: To display an application in the middle of the screen on a solid colour background. This means nothing else showing no gnome-desktop nothing apart from the application and the solid colour background.

Currently I'm using X11 for the background xstart -solid Grey which is great however as a test application I'm running firefox which I see has no window decorations ie: max, min title or boarder neither for that matter does xterm. I was wondering if it is possible to show the decorations without installing gnome possibly by installing just the themes eg: gnome-themes which I have done but have been unable to make the connection, or weather just running X isn't going to work without more gnome modules. I'm new to delving into the inner workings of linux as I've never had to deal with it before. I did ask a question previously which led me to xstart and xsetroot and I've been playing around with them for a bit trying to familiarise myself.

I do recognise that it is possible that I have gone about this all wrong, but if we don't try we don't learn.

If anyone knows of any tutorials or documentation that could help or if anyone has any tips I'd be grateful for the pointers.

Cheers

Chris

SOLUTION

Just thought I'd mention that I solved my issue after installing an ubuntu server distro I added xinit via apt-get then added metacity Then I edited the gconf files using gconf-editor then removed the Gnome-panels from /usr/bin However as I may possibly require them in the future I have made a copy of them before I deleted them. Thanks again for the help it was much appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in programming, or in the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I think I understand what you are asking. Gnome is a "Desktop", and includes with it one of many "Window Managers" called Metacity if I remember correctly. That is the part that adds the title and borders etc. There are many pure window managers(not desktops). A common and popular "Window Manager" is fluxbox although there are many others. Fluxbox does allow you to "undecroate" a window when you launch it. I'm not sure if this is what you are asking. Hopefully it is of some help.

Answer (score 2):

The window decorations are created/managed by the window manager. If you don't have one running, you won't get window decorations.

Comment: cheers for that I'll look into it, sounds obvious really, maybe its just been a long day lol